# How can I get Cloud Functions for Firebase local testing working?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having trouble getting local testing working for Cloud Functions for Firebase. I'm following the instructions here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator Here's the command I run and error I get:

$  firebase serve --only functions

⚠functions: Cannot start emulator. Error: Cannot find module 'node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding'

node-modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js exists in my project directory, so I'm not sure why it can't find it.